# Problem after tabu package update when using xcolor

Tags: color, tabu

After tabu package update X[-1] produces error when xcolor package is used:

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{tabu}
\usepackage{xcolor}

\begin{document}

\begin{tabu} to \linewidth {X[-1]X[1]}
    cell 1 & cell 2 \\
    cell 3 & cell 4
\end{tabu}

\end{document}
```

error code:

```
Missing } inserted. \end{tabu}
```

X[-1] is usefull to produce fixed width tables with variable column width according to the content width. The code compiles without error when x[1] is used instead or when xcolor package is removed.

Comment: Check the readme here https://github.com/tabu-fixed/tabu, then check the issues and if yours is new add it to the list.

Comment: Thanks, the issue is already reported:
https://github.com/tabu-fixed/tabu/issues/1

Answer (score 1):

The new LaTeX3 package [`tabularray`](https://ctan.org/pkg/tabularray) is an alternative to the outdated `tabu` package:

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{tabularray}
\usepackage{xcolor}

\begin{document}

\begin{tblr}{
  width = \linewidth,
  colspec = {X[-1]X[1]},
  hlines,
  vlines,
  row{odd} = {blue8},
  row{even} = {purple8},
}
  cell 1 & cell 2 \\
  cell 3 & cell 4
\end{tblr}

\end{document}
```

[image]